# Calling for list but getting error "The action 'show' could not be found for SubjectsController"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am following the Lynda tutorials on rails and I have defined the list action in addition to the list.html.erb file with corresponding information.

However when I proceed to access the ~/subjects/list I get this:

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'show' could not be found for SubjectsController

This is the code from my controller:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

  def list

    @subjects = Subject.order("subjects.position ASC")

  end

end
```

Thank you!

Update: This is what I am getting from Rake routes

```
 rake routes
    subjects GET    /subjects(.:format)          subjects#index
             POST   /subjects(.:format)          subjects#create
 new_subject GET    /subjects/new(.:format)      subjects#new
edit_subject GET    /subjects/:id/edit(.:format) subjects#edit
     subject GET    /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#show
             PUT    /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#update
             DELETE /subjects/:id(.:format)      subjects#destroy
```

UPDATE:

Code for the view list.html.erb:

```
    <div class="subject list">
  <h2>Subjects</h2>

  <table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
    <tr class="header">
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Visible</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= subject.position %></td>
      <td><%= subject.name %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
      <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
      <td class="actions">
        <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
        <%= link_to("Edit", '#', :class => 'action edit') %>
        <%= link_to("Delete", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have something like this in your `routes.rb`?

`resources :subjects do
  get 'list', on: :collection
end`

Comment: I only have this,   SimpleCms::Application.routes.draw do
  
  resources:subjects

Comment: Do you have a link to show a subject in your view?

Comment: Why would I need to even touch Routes.rb when the tutorial hasn't even mention it? Is this related to the Lynda tutorials being a bit older version?

Comment: In your `rake routes` output you don't have any route which can respond to `subjects/list` (there's no url for it), that's why you need to modify your `routes.rb`

Comment: Dave, I think my view is fine since it is a pre-made one, and I do have a loop that runs through all the subjects. I have updated showing what I get from rake routes.....not sure why it is not showing list.

Comment: @Prussian Because you haven't added a `list` RESTful action. But the error has nothing to do with `list`, but is complaining there is no `show` method. If that's happening when you try to access `list` then there's likely a link to the non-existent method. Please use **@** tags when replying directly to a user.

Comment: @sauronnikko, I did not create the other ones and they are already there since I am following Rails convention and list is part of the standard CRUD I thought it would be generated just like the other ones...

Comment: @Prussian `list` isn't "part of the standard CRUD"; that's `index` in Rails. The routes you get from `rake routes` are the routes that exist; if you don't see it, it's not there. Please use **@** tags when replying directly to a user.

Comment: @Prussian The new, completely unrelated error message indicates you may not have run all your migrations, or have not correctly defined your migration. This should be a new question, and should include the relevant portions of the related models.

Comment: And there is the link to `show`, as I said originally.

Comment: @Dave I know Dave. I noticed that and included the entire code. See my comment below regarding why it is strange that it would work for the Lynda guys when they are using "show" to produce the "list" and defining show has not been done at that point in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify your `resources :subjects` line to make it look like this

```
resources :subjects do
  get 'list', on: :collection
end
```

This way, a subjects/list url will become available in your app.

Let me explain myself more: `resources :subjects` creates by default 7 routes (urls), which are related to 7 actions in your `SubjectsController` (for example, the `GET` http resquest type + `/subjects` url will call the `index` action). Look at your `rake routes` output (from your question post) to understand more. If you want to have more urls which begin with `subjects/`, you can add lines like the following inside the `resources` block:

`get 'list', on: :collectio`n

That just means a `subjects/list` url called by the `GET` http method will be created. The `on: collection` means the url won't be something like `subjects/1/list`.

For more information, I recommend reading [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: `The action 'show' could not be found for SubjectsController`

Comment: I noted the Lynda tutorial was in fact using the show method during the loop in view list.html.erb (see question post), without having defined the show method. Was that an error on their part or was that possible in earlier versions without getting the error I was getting?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a changelog confirming this, but I highly suspect that the problem you are having is due to a difference between Rails 3.x and Rails 4.

I recently went through the same Lynda.com tutorial and he is definitely using Rails 3 and there are a handful of places where things he does do not line up perfectly with how Rails 4 works. For example, when he generates migrations there are `up` and `down` methods whereas in Rails 4 I get a single `change` method.

So I'm pretty sure your issue is another example of the this because I, like you, see that `resources :controllername` does *not* result in a route for controllername/list. My hunch is that /list has been merged into the /index action (which is how I sidestepped the issue), but I'm not enough of an authority to say whether or not this is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently went past the exact same problem. As SDP pointed out, there are some differences between Rails 3.x and Rails 4. Rails 4 needs the Show template to be already available, even if you haven't clicked the Show button on your subjects/list url. The easiest way to solve your problem is to temporarily put a placeholder ('#') in the links in your view until the next chapter of the tutorial, where you get to code the Show template and action.